# If statement in ajax to working? Output received too late?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to get the result of the invoice status (which works, I get 0 if unpaid and 1 if paid | it gets echoed on the website). If 'result' = 1 I want to alert the user, that the invoice was paid, if it's 0 it should remind him to pay the invoice. But every time it just skips to the 'horribly wrong' alert, what's wrong with my code? A hint could be, that if the output is only shown after I click the alert away. What's wrong with my code?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "checkinvoice.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {search: $(this).val()},
                success:function(result) {
                    $("#result").html('Payment Status: ' + result);
                    if(result == 1 ){
                        alert('Yey, invoice paid : )');
                        addGem();
                    } else if(result == 0)  {
                        alert('Lol, just pay');
                    } else {
                        alert('Something went horribly wrong : /'); <-- the only output that's shown
                    }
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert('Uups, something went wrong : /');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Also, as you see I want to run the function 'addGem()' but (of course) same as the alert, it also gets executed if the invoice isn't paid.

```
    function addGem() {

        $.ajax({ url: "gemadder.php",
            data: {action: 'search'},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(output) {
                        alert(output);
                    }
        });
    }
```

So, what's wrong? Hope there is someone who can help

PS: I am pretty new to ajax / js pls excuse beginner errors.

---

If I add console.log(result) to the first line of success function I get:

```
<html>
<body>
0</body>
</html>
```

But the weird thing is, that my post only leads to this:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) { 

    $LightningController = new App\Http\Controllers\LightningController();
    $status = $LightningController->checkInvoice( $lnbits_url, $pmthash, $lnbits_apikey );

    $_SESSION['pmthashstatus'] = $status;
    
}
```

Here is the *part* of the LightningController.php which I think causes the error:

```
    $data = json_decode( $data);

    if ($data->paid == true) {
        $paychecker = 1;
    } else {
        $paychecker = 0;
    }

    return $paychecker;
```

Comment: If it's showing that message it must mean the result didn't contain what you intended it to. Do some debugging. E.g. Put `console.log(result)` as the first line of your "success" function in your ajax call to checkInvoices.php, and tell us what it shows up

Comment: The output is <html>
<body>
0</body>
</html>

Comment: So as you can see it's outputting HTML as well as the result value. Therefore it never equals 1 or 0 as a direct comparison. Remove the code from the php file which causes the html output.

Comment: @ADyson The thing is that I don't really know how that even happens. I have added the only possible part to cause this issue to my question, please take a look : )

Comment: @hacker-root if there is always 1 and 0 that comes and you don't want to change anything on php. Then put ```if(result.includes(1)) .... elseif(result.includes(0)) ... else ...```. I really don't recommend it this way

Comment: None of the code you've shown actually echoes any data though, so it can't be in that bit. At least you found a workaround for now though